# Installing Laravel gives Error

Tags: laravel

I try to install Laravel 5.4 in windows 10 but during the installation it gives this **error** :

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Hôte inconnu.  failed to
>   open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Hôte
>   inconnu.

Comment: You get pretty expressive error, consider yourself lucky. Now copy part of it and put it in the google see what pops up.

Comment: I was searched on google before asking the question if someone have the same problem

Comment: @toto01 If you searched for information about your problem, please explain in your question _what information you found_ and _why that information did not help you_.

Answer (score 0):

1. open the terminal (Win + R) and run  **composer** check if it works or not ?
2. if it works then you have to refresh the web server by running this command .

**sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart**  OR **sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart**

else install the composer once again . [Watch here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZocYVPP3nQY)

3. then run this command for installing laravel

**composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.4.*"**